# node.js synchronous call gather results

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a table where Persons are saved an their time (in seconds) where they were active. 
I would like to write a function that gathers the total time in another table called `gather`.

For each row I am checking if an entry in the `gather` table exists. Depending on that result I make an insert or an update.

```
db.serialize(function() {
    db.each("SELECT * from TEST", function(err, row) {
        db.get("SELECT * from GATHER where name = " + row.name "", function(err, row) {
            if(row === undefined || row === null){
                var stmt = db.prepare("INSTER INTO gather (name, time) VALUE(?,?)");
                stmt.run([name, seconds], function(error){
                    console.log('lastInsert ' + this.lastID);
                }); 
                stmt.finalize();
            }else{
                seconds += row.time;//increment time
                var stmt = db.prepare("UPDATE gather SET time = ? WHERE name = ?");
                stmt.run([seconds, row.name], function(error){
                    console.log('lastInsert ' + row.idProcessed);
                }); 
                stmt.finalize();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem that I ecounter is that sqlite runs asynchronously. Therefore multiple entries are created in my `gather` table although lines should be updated.

What would be the right way to run this function sychronously? Should I limit the lines and call the function every second or is there a smarted way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async). For example (but first you should read final notes at the end):

```
var async = require('async');

var data = {}

var yourFirstSelect() = function(callback){
  //You do your first select 
  //...
  db.get("SELECT * from TEST", function(err, row) {
    if(row){
      data.name = row.name;
      data.otherInterestingAttribute = row.otherInterestingAttribute;
      callback(err, data);
    }else{
      callback('Row is null');
    }
  })
  //..
}

var yourSecondSelect() = function(data, callback){
  //You do your second select 
  //...
   db.get("SELECT * from GATHER where name = " + data.name "", function(err, row) { //Note that I'm using data instead of row
    if(row){
      data.seconds = row.seconds;
      data.otherInterestingAttribute = row.otherInterestingAttribute;
      callback(err, data);
    }else{
      callback('Row is null');
    }
  })
  //..
}

var decide() = function(data, callback){
  if (data.somethingExists) { //Do your validations
    data.type = 'update';
    callback(err, data);
  } else {
    data.type = 'insert';
    callback(err, data);
  }
}

var update() = function(data,callback){
  if (data.type === 'update') {
    //...
    //Do your stuff in order to update
    seconds += row.time;//increment time
      var stmt = db.prepare("UPDATE gather SET time = ? WHERE name = ?");
          stmt.run([seconds, row.name], function(error){
            console.log('update ' + row.idProcessed);
          }); 
      stmt.finalize();
    //...
  } else {
    callback(err,data);
  }
}

var insert() = function(data,callback){
  if (data.type === 'insert') {
    //...
    //Do your stuff in order to insert
    var stmt = db.prepare("INSTER INTO gather (name, time) VALUE(?,?)");
        stmt.run([data.name, data.seconds], function(error){
          console.log('lastInsert ' + this.lastID);
          callback(err,data);
        }); 
        stmt.finalize();
    //...
  } else {
    callback(err,data);
  }
}

var niceWorkflow = function(){
  async.waterfall([
      yourFirstSelect,
      yourSecondSelect,
      decide,
      update,
      insert
  ],
  function (err, result) {
    console.log('Done');
  })
}

//and call your workflow
niceWorkflow();
```

Off course this is not a 100% working code, I wrote it in order you look another way to do what you are trying. Many variables, validations and more are just examples and I intentionally forgot the db.each to avoid being too extense and confusing you and trying to answer your final question `Is there a smarter way?`.

Comment: Semms like a smart way! The problem yet stays the same. The db.each would deliver multiple rows at once and i would like to tell it explicitly to handle one after another because every row the depends on the result before.

Comment: @Silve2611 Hi, did you solve your problem? I didn't comment here before because I was very bussy but you can use eachSeries to do the for loop over the array results of the first query.

Comment: I found a solution with whilst, which is working for me but i an not sure if it is the smartest. I am not really sure i could apply each series here. db.get only returns the first row. db.each would not return an array but give me a callback that would run asynchronous. Do you see a smarter solution? I could also post mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Q.all from [Q library](https://github.com/bellbind/using-promise-q#joined-promise-of-multiple-promises).
It will return a promise after all the promises are resolved. It one promise fails, then Q.all will be rejected.

Comment: Could you explain how this could be done using db.each? I find the approach very interesting und I have read upon promises. I will try it but yet I am have no idea how I can tell db.each to perform one row after another.

Comment: What library are you using, any ORM? I mean, what is db? did you check on [Sequelize](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: If db.get is already returning a promise, you just need to create an array of **db.get**s:

Comment: I am only using sqlite for node.js by now. I think you are write with the db.get method. The method only returns the first row but i should call it in a loop, so i can synchronize it.

Comment: Well, I've never used SQLite, but you should give a try to Sequelize.